# Issue with magento subtotal value

Tags: cart, javascript

I’m trying to calculate a value by subtracting the magento subtotal of my cart from another value, let’s say 50.
This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function minus_number() {
        var a  = document.querySelector("#spend");
        var first_number = '50.00';
        var second_number = '<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); ?>';
        var result = parseInt(first_number).toFixed(2) - parseInt(second_number).toFixed(2);
        a.innerHTML = result.toFixed(2);
    }
window.addEventListener("load",minus_number());
</script>
```

Now it kind of works, but the result isn’t right. I think the issue is that the magento subtotal doesn’t include decimals? So if let’s say the subtotal is 6.98 the result is 44.00 so I assume it only subtracts the 6?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`. Everything else should be working ok.

Comment: welcome back :-)